# References For Important Hopf Algebras 

Tags: hopf-algebras, reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry, textbook-recommendation

Where can I find references that discuss important classes of Infinite Hopf Algebras. By important classes, I mean heavily used in research and of relevance to Hopf Algebraist(s),Physicists, Analysts(Real/Complex),..etc.

Comment: Is "infinite" a special term here or do you mean "infinite-dimensional"?

Comment: I mean that the number of elements is not finite.

Comment: I would have thought that Hopf algebras with only finitely many elements are rare (you'd need the ground field to be finite, for a start)

Comment: (Clarification: rare compared to all possible Hopf algebras)

Comment: I don't have enough rep to edit, but "Algebras" in the title is misspelled. I also retagged because it seems any textbook on Hopf algebras would do for this, and that's what I suspect all the answers will be.

Comment: Just take the group ring over an infinite (commutative) ring.  

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Shahn Majid](http://www.maths.qmw.ac.uk/~majid/Welcome.html)'s book *Foundations of quantum group theory* (Cambridge Univ. Press 1995, 2000) has lots of examples and of classes of examples. These are not only examples of quantum groups in the narrow sense (cf. the $n$Lab [page](http://www.ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quantum%20group) for other references on quantum groups in various senses).